# How to handle WndProc message for a WPF textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to know if I have completed an input word on a wpf textbox, but `TextChanged` event will fire even if I am typing in IME input. Therefore, I try to distinguish `WM_IME_CHAR` from `WM_CHAR` message (like I did in c++ windows form). I can get window message for a WPF window using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf?rq=1), but how can I get the message specifically for a textbox inside WPF window?

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HwndSource hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(myTextbox) as HwndSource;
    if (hwndSource != null)
    {
        hwndSource.AddHook(WndProc);
    }
}

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    const int WM_CHAR = 0x0102;
    const int WM_IME_CHAR = 0x0286;
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CHAR
            Console.WriteLine("WM_CHAR:" + wParam);
            //this is for testing
        case WM_IME_CHAR
            Console.WriteLine("WM_IME_CHAR" + wParam);
            //do something if myTextbox receive an IME char...
            break;
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

My above code cannot get any message for textbox. Is anything I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

I'm using VS2015 on windows 10.

If I focus on `Window` and type something in English, I can get `WM_CHAR` message and the correct `wParam`.

If I click on `TextBox`, I cannot get any `WM_CHAR` message.

If I focus on either `Window` or `TextBox` and type something in Chinese Input Method, I cannot get any message.

Comment: I don't have a convenient way to send `WM_IME_CHAR`, but otherwise the code above works fine for me. When I hook the `HwndSource` obtained from a `TextBox` instance, I get all the window messages for that object. You will need to provide more context, and a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, to understand better why this isn't working for you.

Comment: For what it's worth, in my tests I can get `WM_KEYDOWN` messages, but I never see `WM_CHAR` messages. It is possible that those messages are never dispatched to the `HwndSource` object. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587052/whether-we-can-get-wm-ime-messages-when-we-re-typing-in-wpf-textbox-with-ime. The OP there states (without citing reference) that the `HwndSource` hook will not receive `WM_IME_CHAR` messages.

Comment: Seems the OP have the same issue. I tested to focus on `Window`, and can get `WM_CHAR` message, but not for `TextBox`

Comment: WM_CHAR is special.  I think you have to do something non-trivial with IKeyboardInputSink.  Surely there's a better way but you did not mention why you are trying to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After google around, I found an article: [imeで変換状態中でもtextbox-textchangedが発生する](https://yone64.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/ime%E3%81%A7%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E7%8A%B6%E6%85%8B%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82textbox-textchanged%E3%81%8C%E7%99%BA%E7%94%9F%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/)

Simply, I register three events:

```
TextCompositionManager.AddPreviewTextInputHandler(textBox1, OnPreviewTextInput);
TextCompositionManager.AddPreviewTextInputStartHandler(textBox1, OnPreviewTextInputStart);
TextCompositionManager.AddPreviewTextInputUpdateHandler(textBox1, OnPreviewTextInputUpdate)
```

So I could know a `WM_IME_CHAR` is typed when `PreviewTextInputStart` event is fired. When `PreviewTextInput` event is fired, I could know a word is completed.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way in this answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33105412/5665980

```
ComponentDispatcher.ThreadPreprocessMessage += (ref MSG m, ref bool handled) => {
        //check if WM_KEYDOWN, print some message to test it
        if (m.message == 0x100)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Key down!");
        }
    };
```

It should be noted that this technique will receive messages from every window that uses the current dispatcher, but you can filter by hwnd.